# What are some tips of curating a dataset to fine-tune a code-completion LLM?

Tags: datasets, large-language-models, fine-tuning

There is a new SDK that I am working on and I want to know what are some ways of automatically curating a dataset to train a code-completing LLM to deploy as a VSCode plugin? Hacky ways are appreciated. I was thinking of using chatgpt API to make numerous API calls to inflate a CSV with artificially generated prompts - code entries. There are available datasets of course but I want to tailor the code completion for this particular SDK.

Appreciate all answers.